# Multiple Left Joins - Duplicates - Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

My main problem I can't phrase this in a SQL / Access formatted question...

I have my primary table X which has all of my VM information.  X then left joins the VM's to a table containing storage, call it Y.  Y then left joins that storage to a disk called Z. That gives me an entry for every time there is a row in X * every row in Y * every row in Z.  But Y may link to multiple values in X.  Thus it could appear more than one, just not more than one of the same value in X.  Does that make sense?

Then I have a separate table which also joins off of X.  This table has application information for the VM's.  I am trying to LJ A onto X, providing even more duplicates.  The ideal solution is to build an application where you can run another query but I don't have that option.  Is what I'm trying to do possible in Microsoft Access (Or any DB)?

Comment: You explained your situation, but you did not explain what you are trying to do. If you join a table to another table where there is a one-to-many relationship you will get duplicates from the first table and distinct values from the second. How else would you want it displayed?

Comment: That's my problem is I am struggling to frame my question.  I was hoping writing it out would help me but I still don't have a solution.  I want all unique values from X or the VM names with all of the corresponding information to those VM's in the least # of rows....  I don't think this is possible without doing a dashboard of some nature.  I was mostly using SO as a way to think through my task and hoping someone had a suggestion that would be amazing :).

Comment: Well... you probably aren't going to get any suggestions until you figure out how you want to display this data. The need to display a one-to-many relationship on a UI is pretty common. Sometimes the display software an suppress repeated rows. Or you could try to mash everthing into an Excel Pivot Table or something, but that has it's own constraints. Figure out how you want it to look and then perhaps we can help out.

Comment: How about describing the data you have (which you have partially done already) and the result you want to achieve?  And how about presenting the query(-ies) you have been trying that fail to achieve what you want?

Comment: I think you should give us some examples of your table with some sample data. I also think you may be getting confused on the correct joins to use. Also, if Y performs a left join on Z, Z is not guaranteed to return every row.